# Separate each word from a text (maybe more gaps between the words )

Tags: c#

Ηow to easily separate each word from a text (maybe more gaps between the words ) in order to calculate the Hash table

For example :

they give me : 
"An electric car is an automobile that is propelled by one or more electric motors, using electrical energy stored in batteries or another energy storage device. Electric motors give electric cars instant torque, creating strong and smooth acceleration."

i need to separate  each word because i will assign each word in a tree depending on the hash table

Comment: Use .Split() function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks of any effort to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Split Method,and i have used String.ISNullorWhiteSpace to Filter out if the word has more spaces.Here is the query

> ```
> String test = " This is test     method with more    space  ";
>
>         var Result = test.Split(' ').Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
> ```

Result will hold all the splited string without space.you can loop through and use it for your HashTable.